# How to show error message on standard detail page from apex controller?

Tags: controller, error-messages, order, detail-page

I have a button called Sync on Order object.
I want to sync only those orderlineitems whose IsSynced field has value as 'No'. If there are no such orderlineitems then i want to display a message on Order detail page say 'No more orderlineitems to Sync'.

Comment: Sync is a button on Order object which executes a javascript & calls the controller via trigger on after update event. Now suppose my list has no rows to return(i.e no records with Sync='Yes'), so i put a condition like this: if(list.size()>0){ call controller } else { addError}. Now the problem is whenever i make an update on Order object it is not allowing me to save(giving the add error message- No more records to sync)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `addError` function? It helps to add error messages. You can add it in your trigger so that when there are no more records to sync it'll give the message.

Example:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {} 


Trigger.new[0].addError(new myException('no more items to sync'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an error message from your controller, you need something like this:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'my error msg'));
```

Plus, you need to include `<apex:pageMessages id="messages"/>` on your Visualforce page and make sure you rerender it after your action runs.